# How to replace label tags in Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

The task is to **replace** label tags in the Zend Form by any others (i.e. div) using decorators or something
Now I have

```
<label for="field1" class="required">Field1</label>
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="" size="20">
```

What I want to have

```
<div>Field1</div>
<input type="text" name="field1" id="field1" value="" size="20">
```

Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: on which version you are working of zf?

Comment: I'm working with v1.12

Comment: chandresh_cool's answer should work. Please could you edit your question to include your decorator code based on that answer, and the HTML it is producing

Comment: Try using a custom view script. I'll post an example if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Somethin like this

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
array('ViewHelper'),
array('Errors', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'error')),
array('Label', array('tag' => 'span')),
array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'label')),
```

));

For more reference visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546135/zend-framework-decorators-wrap-label-and-viewhelper-inside-a-div)

Comment: No, it's just place label tag inside spans, but I need to replace label tag.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if that is possible with the label, I guess you would have to rewrite how the label elements are rendered in the form. I managed simply to to the same using the description tag:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm col-md-12">
   <span class="input-group-addon">Name of the field</span>
   <input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" name="name">
</div>
```

This is done by using a decorator like:

```
public $inputDecorators_md12 = array(
        'ViewHelper',        
        array('Description', array('escape' => false, 'tag' => 'span', 'placement' => 'prepend', 'class'=>'input-group-addon')),
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'input-group input-group-sm col-md-12'))
    );
```

Note that you can define any type of tag that you want for the description.

so instead of

```
$field->setLabel('fieldlabel')
```

you can do:

```
$field->setDescription('fieldlabel')
      ->setDecorators($this->inputDecorators_md12);
```